# How to permanently disable/disappear this floating toolbar in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

When I press F8 to hide the main toolbar, this floating toolbar then appears:

[image]

(I can click the two arrows button on the right of course, but this just brings back the main toolbar, which I wanted to hide.)

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (Continuous Release | Version 2022.001.20085).

Comment: Look in View, Show/Hide to show and remove things. That is what I do.  I should add I keep many tools down the right side.

Comment: @John: But I have to do that every time?

Comment: Not on my Adobe Acrobat Pro DC machine. The toolbar stays at the top where I need it.

Comment: @John: But as stated, I want to hide the toolbar. Not have it at the top.

Comment: I do not think you can completely hide it permanently. It has to be fixed or floating.  That is how Adobe works.